# Galois classes of L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, selberg-class

Around one month ago, I posted on math.stackexchange a draft I wrote in which I define the notion of Galois class of L-functions: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280876/definition-of-a-peculiar-quotient-group-of-isometries

Edit: As Marc Palm asked for it, I copy and paste this draft here:

"Main ideas towards a proof of GRH

Definition 1

Let $A$ be be a subclass of the Selberg class containing 1, closed under products, and such that every element of $A$ can be factored in a unique fashion in a product of primitive elements of $\mathcal{S}$, these primitive elements belonging to $A$. Such a subclass of $\mathcal{S}$ will be called a Galois class of L-functions.

Definition 2

Let $A$ be a Galois class of L-functions. $T$ is an automorphism of $A$ iff the following properties simultaneously hold true:

1) $T$ is a bijective map from A to itself
2) $T$ maps a primitive element of $A$ to a primitive element of $A$
3) for all $F$ in $A$, the degree of $F$ and the degree of $T(F)$ are the same
4) for all $F$, $G$ in $A$, $T(F.G)=T(F).T(G)$

Definition 3

$\tilde{\phi}:F\mapsto\phi\circ F\circ \phi^{-1}$ is said to be an isometric automorphism of $A$ if $\tilde{\phi}$ is an automorphism of $A$ and $\phi$ is an isometry of the complex plane preserving any rectangle centered in 1/2.

Proposition 1

$\tilde{\phi}(F)=F$ implies $\phi(0)=0$.

Definition 4

A group of equivalence classes of isometries is said to be nice iff each equivalence class contains exactly one representant $\phi$ such that $\phi(0)=0$.

Let $F\in A$ and let $G_F$ be the group of all equivalence classes of isometries preserving the set of non trivial zeros of $F$, where the equivalence relation $R_F$ is defined by : $f R_F g$ iff for every non-trivial zero $s$ of $F$, $f(s)=g(s)$.

Let $G′_F$ be the group of isometric automorphisms of $A$ preserving $F$.

Proposition 2

$G_F$ and $G′_F$ are isomorphic iff GF is nice.

Definition 5

Let $A$ and $B$ two Galois classes of L-functions such that $A$ is a sub Galois class of L-functions of $B$. Let's define the L-type (Isometric) Structure group of $B$ over $A$ as the group of (isometric) automorphisms of $B$ preserving $A$ pointwise. The L-type structure group of $B$ over $A$ will be denoted as $LStr(B/A)$ and the L-type Isometric Structure Group of $B$ over $A$ $LIStr(B/A)$.

Definition 6

Let $GZ(A)$ be the set $\bigcup_{F\in A}\{Z(F):=\{s,F(s)=0, 0<\Re(s)<1\}\}$. The group of all isometries preserving $GZ(A)$ will be denoted as $PG_A$.
Now let's consider the relation $R'_A$ defined by $f R'_A g,$, where $f$, $g$ are elements of $PG_A$, iff for all $F$, $H$ in $A$, 
$f R_F g$ iff $f R_H g$. The quotient group $PG_A/R'_A$ will be denoted as $SG_A$.
Let's now consider the group of elements of $SG_B$ preserving $GZ(A)$ pointwise. This last group will be called "Z-type Isometric Structure Goup of $B$ over $A$" and denoted as ZIStr(B/A).

Conjecture 1

Let $A$ be a Galois class of L-functions, $F$ an element of $A$. $G_F$ is nice iff for all $H$ in $A$, $G_H$ is nice.

Conjecture 2 (Main Conjecture)

Let $A$ and $B$ be two Galois classes of L-functions such that $A$ is a sub-Galois class of L-functions of $B$. Then $LIStr(B/A)$ and $ZIStr(B/A)$ are isomorphic.

Idea of proof: prove that $LIStr(B/A)$ and $ZIStr(B/A)$ are both isomorphic to $Gal(F_B/F_A)$, where $F_B$ is the field generated by the union of all images of $R−{1}$ by the elements of $B$, and $F_A$ is defined in a similar way. If $B$ is the maximal Galois class of L-functions and $A=\{\zeta^{n},n\geq 0\}$, one can expect to have a proof of the Riemann Hypothesis."

My question is: can one hope to establish the isomorphy of the groups $ZIStr(B/A)$ and $LIStr(B/A)$ through Hadamard's factorization theorem (and maybe some other results), or must one necessarily consider the fields $F_A$ and $F_B$?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I offer quite an interesting bounty to anyone who will manage to establish the desired isomorphy rigorously.

Comment: I somehow think that one can rephrase RH for an L-function $G$ as: $ZIStr(T/\langle G\rangle)$ is isomorphic to $Gal(\mathbb{C}/F_{\langle G\rangle})$, where $T$ is the maximal Galois class of L-functions and $\langle G\rangle$ is the Galois class of L-functions generated by $G$. Is this true?
If so, one could try to prove the two following statements:
1) $LIStr(T/\langle G\rangle)$ is isomorphic to $Gal(\mathbb{C}/F_{\langle G\rangle})$
2) $LIStr(T/\langle G\rangle)$ is isomorphic to $ZIStr(T/\langle G\rangle)$.

Comment: If RH is false for $G$, then $ZIStr(T/\langle G \rangle)$ contains two distinct elements (the identity map and the map $s\mapsto \overline{1-s}$) if $F_{\langle G\rangle}=\mathbb{C}$, plus the complex conjugation and the map $s\mapsto 1-s$ if $F_{\langle G\rangle}=\mathbb{R}$.
So if $ZIStr(T/\langle G\rangle)$ is isomorphic to $Gal(\mathbb{C}/F_{\langle G\rangle}$, then RH holds true for $G$.


Comment: Moreover, if RH is true for $G$, then for any zero $s_{0}$ of $G$  $s_{0}=\overline{1-s_{0}}$, thus the identity map and the map $s\mapsto \overline{1-s}$ can't be distinguished considering their action on $s_{0}$, thus they correspond to a single element of $ZIStr(T/\langle G \rangle)$. Same reasoning with the complex conjugation and the map $s\mapsto 1-s$ if $F_{\langle G\rangle}=\mathbb{R}$.
Hence, if RH is true for $G$, then $ZIStr(T/\langle G \rangle)$ is the trivial group if $F_{\langle G\rangle}=\mathbb{C}$, and is a group of order 2 if $F_{\langle G\rangle}=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Much of what you write remains cryptic to me. Please include definitions and explain the notation.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make things clearer. First, do you think you perfectly understand what a Galois class of L-functions is?

Comment: Z in ZIStr stands for "zero", L in LIStr stands for "L-function". On one side you have an L-function whose you consider the isometric automorphisms preserving it, on the other side you have the set of its zeroes whose you consider the set of non equivalent isometries preserving it. "I" stands for "Isometric", "Str" stands for "Structure (group)".

Comment: Okay, most of your definition are given at stack.exchange. Why do you not copy paste them here?

Comment: Done. I'll fix the LaTeX later, when my headache calms down.

Comment: Thank you. I know nothing about the Selberg class, but I'd believe that everything can be writen in terms of primitive things (as products, and so on). Why can't you phrase all your propositions/definitions in terms of primitive things (generators) only?

Comment: It is indeed possible, since RH is true for F=F1.F2...Fn iff it's true for every Fi. I just wanted to remain as general as possible.

Comment: Let $G$ be an L-function and $f$ be the bijection that maps any L-function to the set of its non-trivial zeroes. If I'm not mistaken, one can write: $\tau(\phi):=\tilde{\phi}=f^{-1}\circ\phi\circ f$, where $\phi$ is an element of $ZIStr(T/\langle G\rangle)$. As $f$ is bijective, one has $\phi=f\circ\tilde{\phi}\circ f^{-1}$, hence $\tau$ is itself bijective.

Comment: As $\tilde{\phi}(F)=F\Rightarrow\phi(0)=0$, and as one can deduce from the comment above that $\forall F\in T$, $G_{F}$ and $G'_{F}$ are isomorphic, $\forall F\in T$, $G_{F}$ is nice. Hence $\forall F\in T, ZIStr(T/\langle F\rangle)$ is isomorphic to $LIStr(T/\langle F\rangle)$.